# Why does the "innerHTML" property with <br> doesn't create new lines?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to build a pyramid of "*", and I can see only the last line of it, while with the alert I can see every line. anybody know what is wrong with my code?

```
function build(){
        var x = document.hi.floor.value;
        //alert(x);
        var i;
        var bil= "";
        for(i=0; i<x; i+=1){
            bil = bil + "*";
            //alert(bil);   
            document.querySelector(".py").innerHTML= bil +"<br/>";  
        }           
    }
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdkjsdj0/).

Comment: @Felix I don't think it's a duplicate; `bil` is appended to.

Comment: @Kenney: I see. Well, the issues are pretty related.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fa0tgtg5/). It does what it says. Do you mean you want `bil = bil + "*<br/>"; document.q...innerHTML = bil;`?

Comment: @Kennedy: So I guess he actually does want `document.querySelector(".py").innerHTML += bil +"<br/>";` and it was a duplicate :P . The `bil` stuff is just for building each line. See http://jsfiddle.net/fa0tgtg5/1/

Comment: Duplicate of [innerHTML with For Loop in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996763/innerhtml-with-for-loop-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you Felix, its working :-)

Comment: and thank you too @kennedy. i'm new here, so it took me time to understand what is going on ...

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate your results in the loop, and then output the result afterwards, like this:

```
function build(){
    var x = document.hi.floor.value;
    //alert(x);
    var i;
    var bil= "";
    var html = "";
    for(i=0; i<x; i+=1){
        bil = bil + "*";
        //alert(bil);   
        html += bil +"<br/>";  
    }
    document.querySelector(".py").innerHTML= html;
}
```

You were just overwriting each previous value of `innerHTML` with the latest value of `bil`. So in the end you only had `***<br/>` (for x = 3), and the line-break didn't really show as there was nothing following it.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdkjsdj0/).

Comment: No, actually he had `***<br/>` (see fiddle)

Comment: The `html = bil + "<br/>";` line should probably be `+=` and you don't really need the self-closing `/` character.