# Javascript loop drop-down options

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started learning vanilla JavaScript and I'm trying to create a drop-down menu targeting the HTML snippet.

I attempted to use the loop method to create 25 options but it only displays 1.

My code:

```
<select name="25dropdown" id="25dropdown">

</select>

<script>

function dropDown(){
for (y = 1; y < 26; y++) {
    document.getElementById("25dropdown").innerHTML = ("<option value =" + y + ">" + y + "</option>");
    }
}
dropDown();

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [innerHTML with For Loop in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996763/innerhtml-with-for-loop-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration you are replacing the HTML, but you have to keep the previously added HTML as well. Try `+=` instead of `=`

```html
<select name="25dropdown" id="25dropdown">

</select>

<script>

function dropDown(){
  for (y = 1; y < 26; y++) {
    document.getElementById("25dropdown").innerHTML += ("<option value =" + y + ">" + y + "</option>");
  }
}
dropDown();

</script>
```